# remove only parent element not its childs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get the inner html of one division,and i want to `remove particular elements` from that html, have a look at following html

```
<div id='mainDiv'>
  <p>dont remove me</p>
  <span id='removeSpan'>Remove Me</span>
  <div id='removeDiv'>
    <p>don't remove me</p>
  </div>
  <p>dont remove me</p>
</div>
```

from the above html i want to get innerHTML of `mainDiv` andi want to remove `removeSpan` and `removeDiv` and i dnt want to remove childs of `remove div` what i am doing so far is..

```
var fullHtml = $('mainDiv').html();
var filterHtml= fullHtml .replace('<span id='removeSpan'>Remove Me</span>','');
```

`this working for this element bcoz i dont want childs of this element`
but how ican remove only `removeDiv` [only it's opening and closing tags not childs]
the final result should be following

```
 <p>dont remove me</p>
 <p>dont remove me</p>
 <p>dont remove me</p>
```

thank for immediate responds..
 bt here `i dont want to change my application screen[html]`. i just want to collect that innerHtml(of course after removing like i said) to a variable as a string. can i make this.. sorry for trouble!

Comment: unwrap maybe http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: So, you want to remove all tags in `mainDiv` except for `p` tags?

Comment: Is this always the HTML layout? And you only want the `innerHTML` value of `mainDiv` to be the `p` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've written... a combination of .unwrap() and .remove() will do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('TRIGGER').on('click', function(){
            $('#removeDiv p').unwrap();
            $('#removeSpan').remove();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
// ]]>
</script>
```

.unwrap() will remove the parent from an element while .remove() removes that particular element.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#mainDiv').parent().append($('#mainDiv p')).end().remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kk9xS/)

or

```
$('#mainDiv p').unwrap().siblings('#removeSpan').remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kk9xS/1/)

This one also keeps data and events, and could also be written

```
$('#removeSpan').remove();
$('#mainDiv p').unwrap();
```

**EDIT:**

If you just want the HTML of the P tags in a variable

```
var html = $.map($('#mainDiv p'), function(e) { return e.outerHTML }).join('');
```

or just the paragraphs

```
var p = $('#mainDiv').find('p');
```

or a clone of the paragraphs

```
var p = $('#mainDiv').clone(true).find('p');
```

Comment: unwrapping the `p` elements inside `#mainDiv` wil remove the mainDiv's tags. OP wants to remove `removeDiv`'s tags. So you'll want to reformat that line to `$('#removeDiv p').unwrap();`

Comment: @GroundZero - That's not what the "before" and "after" markup suggests.

Comment: @adeneo - Yes indeed, his after markup doesn't display a *mainDiv*. But his question states he wishes to remove *removeDiv* from the end result. Probably also *mainDiv*, but he didn't mention that explicitly. Anyway, if OP wants both, you'll be fine, as long as the div only contains p-elements you want to keep and no other container (you want to keep) surrounds the p-tags.